# Get the "OR" result of all rows of a bit column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
**ID**  | **read** | **edit** | **delete**|

  1         true       false    false

  2         false      false     true 

  3         true       false     true 

  4          true       false     false
```

I want to "OR" the rows and at last create a row that contain the OR result of them. is there any way to do it without for loop? what is the best way ? (row may be so many and i think for loop may reduce speed)

Comment: You want to `OR` on column-by-column basis, or you want to `OR` each column in one row first and then `OR` all the results?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I want OR all the rows together and just want one result (one row)

Comment: Still don't understand. Do you want something like `(read(1) or read(2) or read(3) or read(4))`, and similarly for other 2 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
cast(max(cast([read] as int)) as bit) as [overall_read],
cast(max(cast([edit] as int)) as bit) as [overall_edit],
cast(max(cast([delete] as int)) as bit) as [overall_delete]
from tbl
```

`a or b` is True when at least 1 of `a` or `b` is True, and False otherwise. So you can directly reduce this to getting the maximum value for each column, as @Joachim has also pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You could just cast the bits to integers and use `MAX` to get the biggest value;

```
SELECT MAX(CAST([read]   AS INT)) [read],
       MAX(CAST([edit]   AS INT)) [edit], 
       MAX(CAST([delete] AS INT)) [delete]
FROM mytable;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8190f/1).